# How to return a React component from function component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create an input select component but when rendering to the interface it doesn't show the options

```
export const SelectFormGroup = (argument) => {
const options = argument.options;
return (
    <Col xs={argument.xsNumber}>
        <FormGroup>
            <label>
                {argument.labelText}
            </label>
            <FormControl
                as={'select'}
                required
                placeholder={argument.placeholderText}
                defaultValue={argument.defaultValue}
            >
            </FormControl>
            {
                options.map((option) => {
                    <option>{option}</option>
                })
            }
        </FormGroup>
    </Col>
);}
```

Comment: what is `Form.js` line 44?

Comment: Line 44 only include one "{". You can check in picture below

Comment: please add `Form.js` code to your question, you just doing some illegal move at the mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while using one-line function if you put `{}` you have to add `return` keyword

```
options.map(option => { return <...option /> })
```

or without `{}` and now the one line turned automatically to be the `return` part

```
options.map(option =>  <...option /> )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the put the collection of options within the FormControl.
Update your FormControl in the SelectFormGroup component as below:

```
<FormControl
      as={"select"}
      required
      placeholder={argument.placeholderText}
      defaultValue={argument.defaultValue}
    >
      {options.map((option) => {
        return <option>{option}</option>;
      })}
</FormControl>
```

Comment: Sorry, it not work. Can you check my edit question?

Comment: You didn't put the return keyword in yours from what i can see. In your map function you need to  return the JSX because your are not doing a one liner.